# How queuing is done in ESBs? I checked AQMP protocol but i dont know how its implemented in various ESBs?

Tags: message-queue, esb, ultraesb

ESBs in focus are :

1. ultraesb,  emule,  Oracle Service Bus  and IBM Integration Bus

Comment: You mean AMQP? By emule you mean Mule ESB?

Comment: yes i am sorry for spelling mistakes, i mean same by AMQP and mule esb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean messaging between the nodes inside an ESB, it's usually a matter of configuration. So for instance in OSB you can choose to use HTTP, direct connection, jms, etc. Mule also uses various transports, vm, jms, etc. You can set this up when you create your node/router/service (definition depends on the product). IIB is similar, but you have to create queuing between separate flows - it is pretty straight forward if using MQ. I don't know ultraesb, however.

Answer (score 0):

IIB has very strong support for all types of messaging, including MQ. Queueing is supported but is not required.